# Issue on installing iperf on ubuntu

Tags: installation, wireless, ubuntu-11.10, apt-get

I am trying to install iperf on ubuntu 11.10. I refer this [site](http://advanxer.com/blog/2012/06/installing-iperf-on-ubuntu/) to install.

After I gave `./configure`, the error would be "`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`"

Then, i found out where is configure, and I have given command as `./iperf-2.0.5/configure`. Then i have followed further step given by that link.

But, If I give `iperf -s -D` command, I am getting the error as given below:

```
The program 'iperf' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install iperf
```

What mistake have I done? Please point it out.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read what that error message said. If you simply run command:

```
sudo apt-get install iperf
```

you will get `iperf` installed without the need to compile it from source - at least it did for me.

That said, please consider using (or least trying) more modern equivalent of `iperf`, namely [`nuttcp`](http://www.wcisd.hpc.mil/nuttcp/Nuttcp-HOWTO.html). `nuttcp` seems to be better supported, and, [according to some sources](http://www.wcisd.hpc.mil/nuttcp/Nuttcp-HOWTO.html), works better.

You can install nuttcp on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install nuttcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented on mvp's answer, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation at the moment.

First of all, to cover your question, if you are building from source like you do, after you run the "configure" script, you should:

```
sudo make
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

**in the folder that the configure script is located**, so in your case in "iperf-2.0.5" folder.

Having said that, I highly suggest that you drop iperf version 2 and move to iperf version 3. As somebody that uses iperf to examine and teach protocols, I believe it follows the protocols much more closely and behaves more predictably.

You can download the source form: https://code.google.com/p/iperf/ and the instructions to install it are similar with the ones you followed and can be found in the README file in the tarball.